# Grunt problems with proxies - Gruntjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have been working all day on trying to get my proxies set up in my Gruntfile.  Here is my `Gruntfile`:

```
var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    connect:{
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [proxySnippet];
          }
        }
      },
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        base: 'app',
        keepalive: true,
        livereload: true
      },
      proxies: [
        {
          context: '/public/api',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 8182,
          https: false,
          rewrite: {
            '^/public/api': ''
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', ['less', 'configureProxies', 'connect', 'connect', 'watch', 'open:dev']);
};
```

When I run my `grunt server` I can only hit my proxy.  If I try to just hit anything other than the proxy I get a `404`.  What is giving me this issue?

Comment: Hi, Did you try my solution ? I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had a lot of trouble setting up a proxy using [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy).

Digging in the source code of [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect), I realized that it uses the `nodeJs` [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) framework behind the scene.

Internally the `middleware` option defaults to this function:

```
function (connect, options) {
    var middlewares = [];
    if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
        options.base = [options.base];
    }
    var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
    options.base.forEach(function (base) {
        // Serve static files.
        middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
    });
    // Make directory browse-able.
    middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));
    return middlewares;
}
```

Which basically adds the `connect.static` and the `connect.directory` middlewares to an array passed to the `connect(middlewares)` constructor.

Knowing that, we can make use of the [proxy-middleware](https://npmjs.org/package/proxy-middleware) `nodeJs` package like this:

```
connect: {
    server: {
        options: {
            port: 9002,
            keepalive: true,
            middleware: function (connect, options) {
                // Proxy all requests to target the local application.
                var proxyOptions = require('url').parse('http://localhost:8080/');
                proxyOptions.route = '/api';
                return [
                    require('proxy-middleware')(proxyOptions), // Include the proxy first.
                    connect.static(options.base), // Serve static files.
                    connect.directory(options.base) // Make empty directories browse-able.
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically we are adding a middleware to the middleware array.
This new proxy middleware will translate any incoming request like `http://localhost:9002/api/` into `http://localhost:8080/`